# TF 2.0 LSTM: How to use for a Spending prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to use the LSTM in TensorFlow 2.0 to predict all customers spending in next month (This may not be a common LSTM use case). My data has 10k customers monthly spending data.

Format:

```
Customer ID,  time(yyyymm), target(spending), age, gender,  all other features.....
customer 1,   201912,       100
customer 1,   201911,       200
...
customer 1,   201402,       300
customer 1,   201401,       100
customer 2,   201912,        0
....
customer 2,   201401,       50
customer 3,   201912,       100
....
customer 10k, 201401
```

It is has 4 dimensions for input of LSTM: `(10k customers * 60 months samples * 3 timesteps (quarterly) * 100 features)`.
Normally the LSTM takes 3 dimensions: `(nb_samples, timesteps, features)`

**My Problem:**

I guess I am still not sure what is the correct approach for my data.I put my starting code below, but I don't think some of my understating is correct:

```
lstm_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(60,3,100), name='lstm_input') 
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, name='lstm_0',return_sequences=True)(lstm_input)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
....
```

What should I change to make my data fit into a LSTM or RNN model?

**UPDATE**

I guess may be I need to make the input like below? Or should I even use RNN/ LSTM to model it?

```
  [         Month1                    Month2                  ...  Month60
customer 1: [[fe1(1,1)...fe100(1,1)], [fe1(1,2)...fe100(1,2)],... ,[fe1(1,60)...fe100(1,60)]]
customer 2: [[fe1(2,1)...fe100(2,1)], [fe1(2,2)...fe100(2,2)],... ,[fe1(2,60)...fe100(2,60)]]
  ....
customer N: [[fe1(n,1)...fe100(n,1)], [fe1(n,2)...fe100(n,2)],... ,[fe1(n,60)...fe100(n,60)]]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this observation helps. For every customer get the total spending for every month.
This way you have a constant number of timesteps (60 months) and 10k samples.
I assume you know all the terms explained [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/).

I also don't understand the *3(quarterly) part, is the data sampled in trimesters?

Comment: Ok, I guess my initial thought was not correct. I see the  *3(quarterly) as time step initially. Now I feel like I should remove this and make the final input array as 3d (10k, 60 months, 100 features) and feed it into an LSTM. I don't know if this is a good practice?